# Можно ли автоматически конвертировать код из VB.NET в C#?

Tags: .net

Предположим, есть некоторые исходники на одном .NET языке и хочется получить их на другом языке.

Существуют ли утилиты автоматической конвертации?

Comment: например http://converter.telerik.com/

Comment: [Convert .NET (Based on .NET 4.5)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fishcodelib.ConvertNETBasedonNET45)

Comment: https://www.tangiblesoftwaresolutions.com/   от страницы до проекта, вот ту про это https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ru-RU/7a2b4c04-d5dd-4ada-a763-96cbde20673f/-c-vbnet-vbnet-c-?forum=fordesktopru

Comment: Да тот же ILSpy умеет декомпилировать в любой из языков.